# Deeplinks in iOS does not trigger the app

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello everyone i am trying to change the deeplinks supported in a project. If i use https://mydomain/share it works but if i want to create a new one /profile for example it does not work. It redirects me to download the app. The weird thing is that the app opens when /share is used in the deeplink but when i use /profile it does not trigger the

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler{ }
```

which is in appdelegate.m of my app. Where should i put the /profile to trigger the specific method ? do i need to update the apple-app-site-association file to my server to support the /profile url?

Comment: I think you'll need to update the AASA file

Comment: yeah that is what i thought. apple-app-site-association = AASA. I should talk to the web developers i guess...